# Random people connecting to my socket on port 8080

Tags: sockets, ip

I was developping an app, and running a server from home on a private IP on port 8080 (This is the only port coming from my IP that is exposed to the internet). Its just a simple java IO socket.

But I constantly have random people trying to connect from random IPs coming from the virgin islands etc.

Not sure if this is normal?
I did register at no-ip...because I have a dynamic IP, not sure if that might be exposing my home IP to some bots scanning things?

If anyone can shed some more light on this, that would be great.
I am running the socket server in sandboxie so that might mitigate attacks somewhat..I just hope its not anything like that. I also implemented some basic authentication now, and it will drop connections if they fail to authenticate..but before that, those random IPs would stay connected for many hours...its so weird.

Comment: People scan the entire Internet all the time. It really doest even matter if there is a DNS record pointing to the IP or not.

Comment: Oh ok, its probably that. Still kinda crazy that there are atleast a few attemps every hour, and they even keep the socket connection open. Doesn't sound like a very efficient scanner :D.

Comment: That's because their motive is often to recruit your system into a botnet.  Or something similarly unwanted by you.  Most real hackers might want to break into the Pentagon to see whether they can do it, but the ones trying to break into your system or mine have other goals in mind.

Comment: Yea alot of the IPs that are trying to connect can be found in this list: http://global-threat.rmjconsulting.net/?op=prv_idstableLimit&limit=5000

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out in the comments. These are indeed people scanning the internet.

Many of the observed IPs can be found in lists like this: http://global-threat.rmjconsulting.net/?op=prv_idstableLimit&limit=5000

I guess that proves again how important network security is and making sure no vulnerable apps are facing the internet.

Was kind of suprised by the frequency that this happens..